# How to prevent discovery of URLs by search engines?

Tags: redirects, search-engines

I crawled my Wordpress site using the Screaming Frog program and noticed a few issues which might have SEO implications and was hoping someone could help identify the problem (if there is one).

**N.B**: I have obscured the domain name in the image as I do not want it made public.

The canonical URL for my domain is prefixed by `https://www` but as you can see from the tree graph image below, there are a number of URLs accessible under the `http` protocol and the non-`www` version of the domain. Those URLs are non-indexable but I'm curious as to why they're accessible at all. I was thinking that shouldn't happen if the proper redirects were in place.

In the Wordpress admin settings I have entered the correct version of my domain for the Wordpress and site addresses (i.e., `https://www`)

It's possible my `.htaccess` file might require editing so I have pasted it below:

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
RewriteRule \.object-cache\.ini - [F,L]

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

### marker DROPQS start ###
CacheKeyModify -qs:fbclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:gclid
CacheKeyModify -qs:utm*
CacheKeyModify -qs:_ga
### marker DROPQS end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
### marker BROWSER CACHE start ###
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType application/pdf A31557600
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31557600
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon A31557600
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31557600

ExpiresByType image/jpg A31557600
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31557600
ExpiresByType image/png A31557600
ExpiresByType image/gif A31557600
ExpiresByType image/webp A31557600

ExpiresByType video/ogg A31557600
ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31557600
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31557600
ExpiresByType video/webm A31557600

ExpiresByType text/css A31557600
ExpiresByType text/javascript A31557600
ExpiresByType application/javascript A31557600
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31557600

ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31557600
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff A31557600
ExpiresByType application/font-woff A31557600
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A31557600
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31557600
ExpiresByType font/ttf A31557600
ExpiresByType font/otf A31557600
ExpiresByType font/woff A31557600
ExpiresByType font/woff2 A31557600

</IfModule>
### marker BROWSER CACHE end ###

## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE
#This Apache config file was created by Duplicator Installer on 2021-02-17 10:08:29.
#The original can be found in archived file with the name .htaccess__[HASH]

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to not make the site accessible is not to serve it. You can block bots by denying access via the user-agent string but that can be spoofed by malicious crawlers.

The example provided makes not attempts at redirecting traffic through the desired URL which lets users and bots crawl the site via 4 versions (https://www.example.com, http://www.example.com, https://example.com and http://example.com). By adding a few lines to your .htaccess file, you can permanently redirect traffic to the three undesired protocol and host combinations which means you will no longer be serving pages with URLs you don't want. There are different ways to do this but here is one:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Without the above or something equivalent, all 4 versions are accessible and even without links to the URLs you don't want, I found that they eventually get accessed occasionally. It's not clear why but I've seen it many times in logs.

Since this is a new site, you may even not redirect at all and return 404 not found since there is no incoming links to preserve but it's usually good to redirect in case users type the site from memory and don't enter it the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks @Itai. I thought the redirections were handled automatically by Wordpress based on the URLs entered in the admin settings. The site's not new, by the way. It's about 5 years old.

Comment: OK. No, you to redirect yourself to controls the URLs to access you site. WP does some redirection for post-names, numbers, categories but the rest is up to you. Since you mentioned you didn't want to make the site public, I assumed it was new. In any case, I recommend redirecting rather than returning 404 at least for people to find it even if they don't remember if it's www.example.com or example.com

Comment: I'm using Cloudflare. In the settings I already had HTTPS set to "always on" and just now added a page rule so that traffic to non-www URLs was redirected to www. After reanalyzing my site, the tree graph still looks the same.

Comment: You should not be able to read any http page if there is a redirect. So there must be pages that are cached. Specially with CND, caches can be spread across many servers and it might take a while for them to be flushed or expire. Presumably your analysis is not using the local cache either, but if it is, its a good idea to clear it too.

Comment: turns out I had a whole bunch of internal links pointing to URLs with HTTP and without www. Got it sorted now. Not sure how much of an impact that would have had from an SEO perspective as the the redirected URLs are non-indexable but it can't hurt to tidy it up.

Comment: There is no impact to SEO for anything that is not indexable. Even if it was, using canonical meta tag, potential issues can be neutralized. They are quite rate too because the http/https and www/non-www version is very common and easily recognizable by the search engines (Google even has setting you can set the preference). Canonical mostly helps when you have more complex URLs that show the same results in different orders, languages, etc or sometime with different branding.

Comment: What do you mean easily recognizable by search engines?

Comment: Meaning that if you serve the same content on http://www.example.com and on https://www.example.com, Googlebot will not treat those as duplicates. In the Search Console, there is an option to chose your *preferred* URL so that one of them would appear in search results. On if you serves the same content on https://www.example.com and https://www.different-example.com, then that would eventually be considered duplicate content and only one of the two would rank well in the Google index. I used to work at Google, not sure if Yahoo and other do the same though.

Comment: And if you didn't set the preferred url in the search Console? I was going to say it's dangerous to make assumptions about how Google ranks web pages but if you actually worked there then you would have a better idea than most. Having said that, they're constantly updating the algorithm and I'm guessing only a few people would have an intimate knowledge of all the inner workings of that algorithm.

Comment: A heuristic will guess but that could mean an inconsistent use of http and https in search results.